# How can I tell if a jq filter successfully pulls data from a JSON data structure?

Tags: json, bash, jq, return-code

I want to know if a given filter succeeds in pulling data from a JSON data structure.  For example:

```
###### For the user steve...

% Name=steve
% jq -j --arg Name "$Name" '.[]|select(.user == $Name)|.value' <<<'
[
   {"user":"steve", "value":false},
   {"user":"tom", "value":true},
   {"user":"pat", "value":null},
   {"user":"jane", "value":""}
]'
false
% echo $?
0
```

**Note:** successful results can include boolean values, `null`, and even the empty string.

```
###### Now for user not in the JSON data...

% Name=mary
% jq -j --arg Name "$Name" '.[]|select(.user == $Name)|.value' <<<'
[
   {"user":"steve", "value":false},
   {"user":"tom", "value":true},
   {"user":"pat", "value":null},
   {"user":"jane", "value":""}
]'
% echo $?
0
```

If the filter does not pull data from the JSON data structure, I need to know this. I would prefer the filter to return a non-zero return code.

How would I go about determining if a selector successfully pulls data from a JSON data structure vs. fails to pull data?

**Important:** The above filter is just an example, the solution needs to work for any jq filter.

**Note:** the evaluation environment is Bash 4.2+.

Comment: For some reason I could not run the command from your question (or) I could demonstrate the usage of the flag `-e` in your logic, it is throwing me an error `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 6, column 25` on `jq-1.5` on my Mac

Comment: Fixed.  Please try again.  The value key wasn't quoted. I've also simplified the above examples, replacing `$(whoami)` with `$Name` where the latter is clearly defined on the line above the scripts.

Comment: Speaking of quoting, use `--arg Name "$Name"`. Otherwise the number of shell words your name parses into is entirely undefined.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ;-)  Yup, I was just keeping the example simple as typically Linux usernames don't have spaces.  Neverthless, your point has technical merit. I've updated the question above.

Comment: *Nod*. bash supports operating systems other than Linux, though -- on cygwin, for instance, names with spaces do happen in practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution that meets all of my requirements!  Please let me know what you think!

The idea is use `jq -e "$Filter"` as a first-pass check. Then for the return code of 1, do a `jq "path($Filter)"` check. The latter will only succeed if, in fact, there is a path into the JSON data.

**Select.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

Select()
{
   local Name="$1"
   local Filter="$2"
   local Input="$3"
   local Result Status

   Result="$(jq -e --arg Name "$Name" "$Filter" <<<"$Input")"
   Status=$?

   case $Status in
   1) jq --arg Name "$Name" "path($Filter)" <<<"$Input" >/dev/null 2>&1
      Status=$?
      ;;
   *) ;;
   esac

   [[ $Status -eq 0 ]] || Result="***ERROR***"
   echo "$Status $Result"
}

Filter='.[]|select(.user == $Name)|.value'
Input='[
   {"user":"steve", "value":false},
   {"user":"tom", "value":true},
   {"user":"pat", "value":null},
   {"user":"jane", "value":""}
]'

Select steve "$Filter" "$Input"
Select tom   "$Filter" "$Input"
Select pat   "$Filter" "$Input"
Select jane  "$Filter" "$Input"
Select mary  "$Filter" "$Input"
```

And the execution of the above:

```
% ./Select.sh
0 false
0 true
0 null
0 ""
4 ***ERROR***
```

Comment: Sounds good! You should accept the answer, for making the future reference valid!

Comment: I think I have to wait 2 days before I can accept it.  Please upvote this answer... I'm just getting started in putting stuff here and I need reputation points!  :-)  I really enjoyed the back-and-forth with you.  I hope to have conversations with you in the future!  Many thanks!

Comment: This seems overly convoluted, take a look at @peak's answer, or mine.

Comment: @Thedward Unfortunately, your solution is too narrow as the jq filter is not necessarily a simple key filter. So, the `has()` function is inadequate. I need to cater to a wide variety of possible filters and I cannot know in advance what the filter is.  That is, I am writing a Bash function that takes as its input the jq filter (and other arguments). The solution I show above is even a simplification of what I'm dealing with. So, when dealing with complexity to begin with, a more general solution is needed. However, thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: @SteveAmerige - If your solution meets your needs, fine, but there is a fundamental problem here, which in brief is that the question is misguided. Consider, for example, the following case: with no input (`jq -n`), the filter `range(0,10)` produces 10 JSON values.  Are these values "pulled from the data"?  Similarly, if the input is 1, the jq filter `2` will produce one value (2). ...

Comment: @peak saying a question is misguided isn't part of the stackexchange mantras: *focus on questions about  an actual problem*. That's what I've done. Part of the problem is that `jq` provides no global option to say that accessing non-existent keys should raise an error. The function `has` is unfortunately inadequate because it requires apriori knowledge of the filter. So, my focus is to find a solution to my problem. I do agree that "pulled from the data" could be made clearer: I want to be able to take a filter and operate upon it to know if it tries to access any non-existent keys or indices.

Comment: @SteveAmerige - When SO users write misguided or problematic questions, the appropriate way to respond is via "comments" such as this, in the hope that the OP will make appropriate modifications or clarifications. The comment can then easily be deleted. You are of course quite correct to observe that jq does not have an option to change the semantics of the built-in functions for accessing the contents of compound objects. jq does not provide the meta-programming builtins that would be required to write a function in jq to ascertain whether a filter attempts to access a non-existent key, etc.

Answer (score 35):

You can use the `-e / --exit-status` flag from the [`jq Manual`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), which says

> Sets the exit status of jq to 0 if the last output values was neither false nor null, 1 if the last output value was either false or null, or 4 if no valid result was ever produced. Normally jq exits with 2 if there was any usage problem or system error, 3 if there was a jq program compile error, or 0 if the jq program ran.

I can demonstrate the usage with a basic filter as below, as your given example is not working for me.

For a successful query,

```
dudeOnMac:~$ jq -e '.foo?' <<< '{"foo": 42, "bar": "less interesting data"}'
42
dudeOnMac:~$ echo $?
0
```

For an invalid query, done with a non-existent entity `zoo`,

```
dudeOnMac:~$ jq -e '.zoo?' <<< '{"foo": 42, "bar": "less interesting data"}'
null
dudeOnMac:~$ echo $?
1
```

For an error scenario, returning code `2` which I created by double-quoting the `jq` input stream.

```
dudeOnMac:~$ jq -e '.zoo?' <<< "{"foo": 42, "bar": "less interesting data"}"
jq: error: Could not open file interesting: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file data}: No such file or directory
dudeOnMac:~$ echo $?
2
```

Comment: Try the examples above again please.  I didn't have value quoted for the jane user.  I've fixed it above.  Note that while using the -e flag gives you the non-zero error code for a non-existent key, it also **badly** gives a non-zero error code for an existing key whose value is either `false` or `null`.  So, this definitely won't work.  The question is very clear that values can include booleans, empty strings, and `null`.  Do you have other thoughts?

Comment: @SteveAmerige: That's a nice observation, am afraid, these are the exit codes, `jq` supports, but it is clearly distinguishable for codes `1` and codes other than that, maybe  you can use that logic?

Comment: With the -e flag, this problem allows us to conclude that for 0 return status: result is from the JSON data. For non-0, non-1 error status: the result is bad in some way (real error case).  For 1 error status: if result is false, then this is actually from the JSON data, so treat it as 0 return status. **The final case is where the return status is 1 and the result is null.**  I have not yet figured out how this can indicate whether the data comes from the JSON input or not.  If we can solve this, the problem is solved. Keep in mind the jq filter can be anything. So, `has()` doesn't help.

Comment: @SteveAmerige: Tried several filters, for it, just couldn't reproduce that particular combination, with `1` and returning `null`

Comment: Simple cases: **Want non-zero return status:** `jq -je '.a' <<<'{}'`  **Want zero return status:** `jq -je '.a' <<<'{"a":null}'`  In both cases, these return 1 and the result is `null`.

Comment: @SteveAmerige: Am out of luck on this, tried parsing the entire `jq` documentation without any luck, :(. Do update the answer or post it here, if you happen to find the logic, will be happy to update the answer

Comment: You may want to remove the `?` from your first two examples, they have no bearing on this situation and add confusion.  They only affect the filter if the input isn't an object (but it is).  I'd also add an example like `% jq -e '.zoo?' <<< '"foo"'` to show an exit status of 4.

Answer (score 2):

***I've added an updated solution below***

The fundamental problem here is that when try to retrieve a value from an object using the `.key` or `.[key]` syntax, `jq` — by [definition](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#.foo,.foo.bar) — can't distinguish a missing key from a key with a value of `null`.

You can instead define your own lookup function:

```
def lookup(k):if has(k) then .[k] else error("invalid key") end;
```

Then use it like so:

```
$ jq 'lookup("a")' <<<'{}' ; echo $?
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): invalid key
5

$ jq 'lookup("a")' <<<'{"a":null}' ; echo $?
null
0
```

If you then use `lookup` consistently instead of the builtin method, I think that will give you the behaviour you want.

---

Here's another way to go about it, with less `bash` and more `jq`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

lib='def value(f):((f|tojson)//error("no such value"))|fromjson;'

users=( steve tom pat jane mary )

Select () {
  local name=$1 filter=$2 input=$3
  local -i status=0
  result=$( jq --arg name "$name" "${lib}value(${filter})" <<<$input  2>/dev/null )
  status=$? 
  (( status )) && result="***ERROR***"
  printf '%s\t%d %s\n' "$name" $status "$result"
}

filter='.[]|select(.user == $name)|.value'

input='[{"user":"steve","value":false},
        {"user":"tom","value":true},
        {"user":"pat","value":null},
        {"user":"jane","value":""}]'

for name in "${users[@]}"
do
  Select "$name" "$filter" "$input"
done
```

This produces the output:

```
steve   0 false
tom     0 true
pat     0 null
jane    0 ""
mary    5 ***ERROR***
```

This takes advantage of the fact the absence of input to a filter acts like `empty`, and empty will trigger the alternative of `//`, but a string — like `"null"` or `"false"` — will not.

It should be noted that `value/1` will not work for filters that are simple key/index
lookups on objects/arrays, but neither will your solution. I'm reasonably sure that to
 cover all the cases, you'd need something like this (or yours) ***and*** something
 like `get` or `lookup`.

Comment: This solution is too narrow. The jq filters are not necessarily simple key selectors.  See my comment in my own solution. Thanks again for your participation.

Comment: More interesting solution would be to lookup recursively, f.i.: `lookup(.a.b.c)`. If there is `.a.b.c` in the json, return it or throw error otherwise. I believe that we need to use some jq functions like `has`, `path`, `map` and walk recursively over all items .[a], .[b] .[c] to find out if .a.b.c exists there.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding... the holiday season and all. Your update is _very_ interesting. So much so that I'm now considering changing this to the accepted answer. It seems to me that on the Bash side that if I do a regex check to inspect the filter to see if it is a simple path filter (e.g., `.a[1].b`), then I can treat that as a separate case that requires walking to determine whether the path exists. If not a simple path filter, then use your above approach. Do you believe that this will then work for all filters? Can you describe how to do the walk?

Comment: To do the simple path check, I've considered that in Bash I could take a filter such as `.a[1].b` and determine the **parent** and the **key**. For example, for the above example, the parent is `.a[1]` and the key is `b`. Then, I can do `jq "$parent | has($key)`. This might be easier than trying to implement a lookup or get in jq. But, I'm open to your thoughts on this.

Comment: I don't think there is going to be an even remotely elegant way to do this properly until (if ever) `jq` changes the way it deals with `null` values. However, I've come up with another abuse of `(to|from)json` — `def unnullify: "(?six)(?<string>\"([^\"\\\\\\\\]*|\\\\\\\\[\"\\\\\\\\bfnrt\\/]|\\\\\\\\u[0-9a-f]{4})*\"){0}(?<chunk>\\g<string>|[^\"]+)" as $rx|tojson|[scan($rx)]|map(.[2]|sub("\\A\"null\"\\Z";"\"\\\"null\\\"\"")|sub(":null,";":\"null\","))|join("")|fromjson;` — that'll turn all `"null"` values to `'"\"null\""` and all  `null` values into `"null"`. To sidestep the issue entirely.

Comment: And, a slightly less ridiculous version: `def unnullify: (..|objects)?|=(with_entries(.value|=(if ([.]|inside([null,"null"]))  then tojson  else . end)));`

Answer (score 1):

Given that jq is the way it is, and in particular that it is stream-oriented, I'm inclined to think that a better approach would be to define and use one or more filters that make the distinctions you want. Thus rather than writing `.a` to access the value of a field, you'd write `get("a")` assuming that get/1 is defined as follows:

```
def get(f): if has(f) then .[f] else error("\(type) is not defined at \(f)") end;
```

Now you can easily tell whether or not an object has a key, and you're all set to go.  This definition of `get` can also be used with arrays.

Comment: You beat me to it! Also, I'd like to point out that your `get` as defined works fine with arrays already.

Comment: @Thedward - I updated the def so that now it makes sense to use if for both objects and arrays.